# Android Gradle Plugin 3.0 Build Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-gradle-3.0

Experiencing issues migrating to **Android gradle plugin 3.0**.

**build.gradle file** on the root of project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Android **Application Module build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath testDependencies.spoon
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

spoon {
    debug = true
    grantAllPermissions = true
    shard = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Trying to compile a project. I am getting compilation errors.

[image]

But once **retrolambda** is added back again then the project compiles and builds successfully. Read through "Known Issues" section and didn't find a fix. I hope somebody experienced this and can help.

Answer (score 5):

If you do encounter a build error after updating the plugin, simply search [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) for the error output or navigate to the related topic, and follow the instructions to resolve the issue.

### Solution: See at Known issues in refer page.

For example, consider the following classpath dependencies included in the build.gradle file of the main project:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1"
        classpath "me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0"
    }
}
```

Now consider the following build.gradle file for another project included in the composite build:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Note that the order of plugins differs from that
        // of the main project's build.gradle file. This results
        // in a build error because Gradle registers this as a
        // different classloader.
        classpath "me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you set

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

Add the [**`me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda`**](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) plug-in as dependency to your **`build.gradle`** file.

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1"
      classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
   }
}

// Required because retrolambda is on maven central
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```

Then Add the source and target compatibility to **`Java 8`** and apply the new plug-in in your **`app/build.gradle`** file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda' // Add this 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId " "
        minSdkVersion //
        targetSdkVersion //
        versionCode //
        versionName //
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

**FYI**

If you're using Android plugin for **`Gradle 3.0.0 or higher`**, your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies. To use a different version of the build tools, specify it using [**`buildToolsVersion`**](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension:buildToolsVersion) in your **module's** `build.gradle`, as follows:

```
/**
   * buildToolsVersion specifies the version of the SDK build tools, command-line
   * utilities, and compiler that Gradle should use to build your app. You need to
   * download the build tools using the SDK Manager.
   *
   * If you're using Android plugin 3.0.0 or higher, this property is optional—
   * the plugin uses a recommended version of the build tools by default.
   */
    android {

        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    }
```

You should ***`upgrade`*** your [**`buildToolsVersion`**](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension:buildToolsVersion) version.

```
android { 
    compileSdkVersion 27 
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Run`**.

Read

- [**`Recent Support Library Revisions`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)
- [**`Migrating to Android 8.0`**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your BuildToolsVersion is up 26

new android studio 3.0 after required minimum buildToolsVersion 26.0.0 update this version in-app module gradle.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
}
```

If you see the buildtool not found error you need install this build tool.

Comment: Don't forget to update/change appCompat Library version of dependencies.

Comment: build tools version is optional from 3.0 gradle plugin but yes, I did make sure and didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure these Lines In App(module) level gradle file

> buildToolsVersion
>
> defaultConfig
> for App Configuration

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but Android gradle plugin 3.0 doesn't support lower than 26.0.2 build tools version.